CommunityToolKit Mvvm 8.2.2 how to register Integer as TMessage
I am trying to register a integer as the TMessage but it does not seem like it possible. If i remember right it was possible in MVVMLightLibs.
This is the code that is giving an error
int lastRecievedInt = -1;

StrongReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<MessengerTest, int>(this, (r, m) => lastRecievedInt = m);

I am getting following error:

CS0452 The type int must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter TMessage in the generic type or method IMessengerExtensions.Register<TRecipient, TMessage>(IMessenger, TRecipient, MessageHandler<TRecipient, TMessage>)


if you need a reference type declare one like https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet/blob/main/src/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm/Messaging/Messages/ValueChangedMessage%7BT%7D.cs or use that if it fits

As you can see in the doc, TMessage needs to be a reference type.
public static void Register<TRecipient,TMessage>
    (this Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm.Messaging.IMessenger messenger,
     TRecipient recipient,
     Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm.Messaging.MessageHandler<TRecipient,TMessage> handler)
     where TRecipient : class
     where TMessage : class;

So, you can't pass a value type like int. Instead, you need to wrap it in a class. For example:
public class IntMessage(int value)
{
    public int Value { get; } = value;
}

